# LWC Showing Related fields in Lighting Datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is it possible to display related fields in a lightning-datatable in LWC?  For example, I want to show the recordtype name.  I am querying RecordType.Name in the Apex.  When I set the columns in my javascript I just enter the name the same way but it does not display in the table.  Here is the javascript for creating the columns:

```
const columns = [
{label: 'Record Type Name', fieldName: 'RecordType.name'},
{label: 'Line_of_business', fieldName: 'Horizon_Product__r.Line_of_business__c'},
{label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name'}
```

];

Thank you!!!

Comment: Thanks but I don’t see the LWC example in the related question?

Comment: you need to follow the same logic in that answer, check the last code snippet in the answer.